# How to apply css for dynamically adding button inside datalist in asp.net c# 

Tags: c#

How to apply css for dynamically adding button inside datalist?

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(); 
Button b1 = new Button(); 
b1.Text = "First"; 
b1.Attributes.CssStyle["CssClass"] = "button"; 
buttons.Add(b1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a CSS Class for your button style and you can use [`CssClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property.

Comment: my code is    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.Text = "First";
        b1.Attributes.CssStyle["CssClass"] = "button";
        buttons.Add(b1); but it is not working 


        Datalist.DataSource = buttons;
        Datalist .DataBind();

Comment: What is the rendered html of the button when you view the page source?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$dlButtons$ctl04$cmdSubmit" value="Fifth" id="MainContent_dlButtons_cmdSubmit_4" />

Comment: did you try what I said. also try `b1.Attributes.Add("class","button");`

Comment: `b1.Text` is "First" but rendred as "fifth" ?

Comment: there are five button inside datalist . i just placed only one one

Comment: <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">



   <asp:datalist id="dlButtons" runat="Server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="5" >
                  <itemtemplate>
                          <asp:button id="cmdSubmit" text='<%#   Eval( "Text" ) %>' runat="server"  />
                  </itemtemplate>
                  </asp:datalist>
</asp:Content>

Comment: List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.Text = "First";   
        //b1.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
        
        buttons.Add(b1);
        


       
        Button b2 = new Button();
        b2.Text = "Second";
        //b2.Command += new CommandEventHandler(b2_Command);
        buttons.Add(b2);
        Button b3 = new Button();

Comment: Button b4 = new Button();
        b4.Text = "Fourth";
        //b2.Command += new CommandEventHandler(b2_Command);
        buttons.Add(b4);

        Button b5 = new Button();
        b5.Text = "Fifth";
        //b2.Command += new CommandEventHandler(b2_Command);
        buttons.Add(b5);

        Button b6 = new Button();
        b6.Text = "Sixth";
        //b2.Command += new CommandEventHandler(b2_Command);
        buttons.Add(b6);
       


        dlButtons.DataSource = buttons;
        dlButtons.DataBind();